# calling max value of a column in sql db using vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

good day everyone! I was trying to get the max value of a column of my table so that I can +1 the value and assign the new value to another record. I want to get the max value then place it on a textbox. I got the code from here as well but I'm encountering an error that says "Type unsigned is not a defined system type." I did some research, and when I try to change "unsigned" to varchar or char, the error becomes "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values." Same thing happens when I try to change the code portion "select max(CAST(productid as unsigned))" into just "max(productid)". I hope you can help me.
here is code:

connect.Open()

```
    command = connect.CreateCommand
    command.CommandText= "select max(CAST(productid as unsigned)) as value from product"
    read = command.ExecuteReader
    While read.Read
        txtprodid.Text = read.GetString(0)
    End While
    read.Close()
    command.Dispose()
    connect.Close()
```

Comment: what is the data type of the productid column?

Comment: `unsigned` sounds like MySQL, but are you really using MySQL? Please tag your DBMS. Also what data type is `productid`?

Comment: You should probably be using an `identity`/`auto_increment`/`serial` column (the syntax varies by database).  You should not be doing this logic in code.

Comment: I'm actually using sql server 2012 and I'm new in using this one. I'm just surfing the net of what would the suitable solution for my problem. The goal was to get the next "unassigned" productid and automatically put it in a textbox right after the previous adding of a record.
and this is how we declared the column of productid:
`ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
PRODUCTID AS 'PROD' + RIGHT('0'+Cast (id as VARCHAR(5) ),6)PERSISTED,`

Comment: can you check if your PRODUCTID column has all numeric data, also can you share sql fiddle or sample data for your table?

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server and you want to be able to get a "next" id then you probably want a SEQUENCE. But you should consider why you want to do this when common convention is to assign the id at the time of insert.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Scope_Identity. Just add it to the end of your Insert and it will return the new ProductID

```
Dim ProdID As Integer
Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection String")
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert whatever...; Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", cn)
        cn.Open()
        ProdID = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using
End Using
```